# Docker exec -it <containerid> dir doesn't work. Why? How to get directory info?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm very new to docker. 
Also I'm using Docker for Windows (ie Image and Container are for Windows OS).

I'm trying to get a list of all the folders and subfolders to resolve another issue I'm having. I read several post and blogs and seems like I should be able to run

```
docker exec -it <container id> dir
```

To get the info as it is suppose to allow me to run commands against the container.
I even ran

```
docker exec -it f83eb1533b67 help
```

which gave me a list of commands (because no one tells what are acceptable 'commands'...) and it is listed. however I get the following message when I run DIR command

```
PS P:\docker\tmp\SqlServerSetup> `docker exec -it f83eb1533b67 dir`

container f83eb1533b671b4462b8a1562da7343185b2dd27e94ff360e0230969d432ec37 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
                                                                                                                                                                                                        [Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"dir","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment":{"ACCEPT_EULA":"Y","attach_dbs":"[]","sa_password":"Pass1.4DBAs","sa_password_path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\secrets\\sa-password"},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
PS P:\docker\tmp\SqlServerSetup>
```

Please note: I don't want to persist a volume. Seems like that option is for people that are trying to reuse data.

UPDATE:
This is the statement that i'm using to create the container:

`docker run -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=Pass1.4DBAs -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -p 11433:1433 --name sqlTraining --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -d microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer`
It works fine. Container is created, but I want to view the filesystem within that container.

Comment: What's the base of your Dockerfile ?

Comment: Which image are you using?

Comment: docker exec -it f83eb1533b67 /bin/bash

Comment: Is the container Windows or Linux-based?

Comment: I don't have exact statement that i ran but i do know it used 
`FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer`. I'll update the original question with the exact command when i can log back in, in a few hours.

I want to eventually get to the point of creating a dockerfile and I found a tutorial but its for Linux container so I'm having to modify for Windows. If i could get help with this question it would help me be able to finish creating dockerfile as i cant tell location of files (database files)

Answer (score 3):

For Windows containers, prefix the command with the command shell (`cmd`) and the `/c` parameter. For example:

```
docker exec <container id> cmd /c dir
```

This will execute the `dir` command on the specified container and terminate.

Answer (score -1):

Try running:

```
docker exec -it <container id> sh
```

to start the interactive shell console. This should help you with debugging.

Comment: Windows generally doesn't have Bash, it has `cmd.exe` or PowerShell at best.

Comment: Oh,  I haven't noticed, that the image container may not be Linux-based...